# How to show Info window in iOS GoogleMaps on tapping on marker using clustering?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, markerclusterer

On my iOS project I use `GoogleMaps` framework and `Google-Maps-iOS-Utils` framework in order to use clustering markers on map.

Without using clustering, just `Google Maps`, when I create severals markers, setting title's property, a tap on it show an info window with the corresponding title.

But when I use clustering, a tap on a marker (cluster or an item, the result is the same) the info window does not appear although the properties title and snippet are filled, why ?

Comment: are you using swift or obj-c?

Comment: The project is in obj-c !

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you got any solution for this?

Comment: Not exactly. When using google-Maps-iOS-Utils for clustering, it's just not possible to show info window : https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/63. The actual solution consist to : do it yourself or not using the info window...if it's possible for you !!!